# Extracting information from tree structured textfile

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a large text file that is structured like a big tree something like this:

```
{ SomeType
    - parameter1 = value;
    - parameter2 = { SomeType2
         -paramter 1 = { SomeType3
                ...
         }
     - parameter3 = { SomeType4
         ...
         - name = "name";
         ...
         }
    - name = "name";
    - more paramters;
}{ SomeType
    - parameter1 = value;
    - parameter2 = { SomeType2
         -paramter 1 = { SomeType3
                ...
         }
     - parameter3 = { SomeType4
         ...
         - name = "name";
         ...
         }
    - name = "name";
    - more paramters;
}
```

The file has over 10k lines and for now i need to find all names that are associated to a certain type.

The problem i have is that for a certain type the name line is often the first line after the Type, but at other places it is after alot of other Subtypes with own names and so on.
So i can't just search line by line for the type and then get the next line that contains "name". Also the same type can be found some levels deeper again.

I can't seem to find an algorithm that works and i can implement with java.

Answer (score 0):

If it's feasible in your circumstances, I'd recommend you to change data representation to one of known representation models like XML or JSON and to use a parser mechanism for concrete data representation format. Luckily, there are lots of stable and effective parser for both XML and JSON.

Comment: The file is a .sbs file from Rational Rhapsody where it stores all the model data, so it can't be changed.

Comment: @dawastl, Maybe there's a Java implementation of a parser for this kind of file?

Comment: Already tried searching for one but had no luck. Since Rhapsody offers a JAVA API most use that for their purposes. I can get the information that i want over the API just fine too, but I would like to try getting the same information through the textfile so i don't need Rhapsody and can run it easyly in batch mode for a whole directory of projects.